# How to make C++ client trust all X.509 certificates without any verification (like in Java)

Tags: java, c++, ssl, grpc

What is the grpc C++ equivalent of Java's InsecureTrustManagerFactory ?

GrpcSslContexts.forClient().trustManager(InsecureTrustManagerFactory.INSTANCE).build()

an insecure TrustManagerFactory that trusts all X.509 certificates without any verification.

In other words - in Java I create a server (private.key + certificate.pem signed by rootCA) and a client that creates SSL-encrypted channel with the server accepting server's certificate without verification (rootCA.pem is not available for the client). Technically it's not recommended but I use it for testing purposes only. I need to do the same for my C++ version of server-client pair. So far my C++ client needs rootCA.pem either through SslCredentialsOptions:

```
    grpc::SslCredentialsOptions sslChannelOptions;
    sslChannelOptions.pem_root_certs  = "rootCA.pem";
    sslChannelOptions.pem_cert_chain  = "";
    sslChannelOptions.pem_private_key = "";
    return grpc::SslCredentials( sslChannelOptions );
```

or through

gpr_setenv("GRPC_DEFAULT_SSL_ROOTS_FILE_PATH", "roots.pem")

Otherwise I get:

ssl_transport_security.c:921] Handshake failed with fatal error SSL_ERROR_SSL: error:0400006b:RSA routines:OPENSSL_internal:BLOCK_TYPE_IS_NOT_01.

Comment: I'm curious; *why* would you *want* to just blindly accept any certificate? Ok, in test code, *maybe*. But in production, certainly not. Or?

Comment: Because that's what my boss wants. He is the one who signs my paychecks. Anyway, if it's doable in Java gRPC, how would you do it in C++?

Comment: A *responsible* engineer *questions* his boss's decisions when he makes an obvious mistake, rather than just roll over and do as he's told.

Comment: But there are provisions added to Java to accomplish it. Do you know how to do the same in C++?

Comment: No. I don't know a direct C++ equivalent. I would *probably* start by looking into OpenSSL.

Comment: Python version of gRPC has similar provisions in "ssl_channel_credentials()" function. Fourth parameter of which is "verify_callback" and can be None to turn off the verification.

Comment: To be clear, gRPC Java does not consider that a "supported" configuration. It happens to work, but isn't a "feature." It's easier to just use plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, gRPC C++ does not support this feature. gRPC C++ only has options to not verify client's certificate but not server's certificate.

Your use case does not seem strong enough for us to support this feature.