# How GRPC C++ trust all X.509 certificates without any verification like java?

Tags: c++, grpc

Java can create trustmanager all certifates through method:

```
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sc.init(null,  new TrustManager[] { new TrustAllCerts() }, new SecureRandom());
```

How to do in GRPC C++ code, i search many method to do, but failed. have any idea?

in URL [How to make C++ client trust all X.509 certificates without any verification (like in Java)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365638/how-to-make-c-client-trust-all-x-509-certificates-without-any-verification-li), told grpc c++ not support this feature, and it's true? if support how to do, please give some suggestion and show code. thanks

Comment: My idea would be to not trust all certs. It's not secure.

Comment: Or you can also search for a way to add the certificate in gRPC.

Comment: @kiner_shah our requirement is this: allow all certificates,  so need method to work around.

Answer (score 1):

With the newer TLS API something like this should work:

```
auto Connect(std::string address) {
    ::grpc::experimental::TlsChannelCredentialsOptions authOptions;
    authOptions.set_verify_server_certs(false);

    //authOptions.set_certificate_verifier(fancy_verifier);

    return ::grpc::CreateChannel(
        address,
        ::grpc::experimental::TlsCredentials(authOptions)
    );
}
```

This API is experimental, that is, unstable - it varies quite a bit between gRPC library versions.